# subdomain not working and added /mysubdomains/devsitename

Tags: subdomain, error

I am having a site www.example.com which working fine and I have a number of sub-domains which are working fine except one.

When I gave the url  **subdomain.example.com** the address bar showing as below

```
subdomain.example.com --> www.subdomain.example.com/mysubdomains/devsitename
```

It added the www and the /mysubdomain/devsitename which is my hosted directory in my server.

Then it came up with **the website you were looking for is unavailable**.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like a redirect? In cPanel, for instance, when you setup subdomains you have the option to setup (or 'manage') a redirection - is this possible?

Comment: Can you give us more information about your server? Are you using cPanel? If not, how do you manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly because your application that you're running is doing this redirection.  You can first try to create a test page call hosting.html ,  then call it from your browser ex: http://subdomain.smarterasp.net/hosting.html  and see if browser URL stays that way. If it does, then it's highly likely that it's your application that's doing the redirection.

If you try it and URL becomes http://www.subdomain.smarterasp.net/hosting.html  ,  then it's server side problem and you'll need to ask tech support to fix it.

Comment: Yes its the application which is did the redirection.